# Windows 10 flashing screen after login

Tags: boot, windows-10, multi-boot, bootloader, efi

I copied the Windows 10 partition and then in the original used the command "`bcdboot e:\windows`" to add the second Windows 10 OS.
 It shows up fine and it even boots, but after I log in I get a black flashing screen. What is wrong? It doesnt do anything if I dont log in. When I do login and it does flash if I do control alt delete it stops and its the normal blue screen.

If I select the task manager the desktop still flashes but the task manager doesnt. Whats up with this? 
It doesnt do anything on the original copy either.